# How do I recognize that I am using REST?

Tags: web-services, rest, terminology

REST looks me so simple that I got a question what is REST. It looks like just any GET URLs I use. 
How do I recognize that I am using REST? 
What is the difference between simple URL like: "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer"
 and another REST service URL. Is it that the URL (hhttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) if return JSON/XML then it is REST, otherwise it is a webpage!

**In other words:**
Given a URL, how do I recognize that I am accessing REST service url or just a webpage. Is it just the return type  that is different. If return type is XML/JSON then REST otherwise simple webpage!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to tell from the URL that you are accessing a *REST* service vs. anything else.

Given that REST is an architectural style, instead of a specific technology, there is no specific bit-pattern or given marker that you should look for.

From your example, you cannot even tell if it returns JSON vs. HTML or some such, as in that case it is very likely that the server is responding to your Accept: string instead of randomly picking one or the other based on the URL (although given that any specific server can respond to any specific URL how it likes, there are probably servers that do determine it in that way).

Comment: Thank you sdg! Criag has confirmed your answer so I now believe that from Client side there is no way to see if it is REST or not. and I missed the point that it is an "Architecture".

Comment: You *can* tell from the client side. You just can't tell from one single URI.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [REST APIs must be hypertext-driven](http://bit.ly/bQPZM6) article by Roy Fielding. He defines what REST is in his "Principled Design of the Modern Web Architecture".

Comment: That is no help for me. I am looking for a simple must distinguishable answer. Wordpress give different RSS based on parameters. Is that REST? http://example.com/?feed=rss , http://example.com/?feed=atom

Comment: You don't find it helpful, even though it's correct, because your question is not answerable: You *can't* decide if an API is REST from a URI alone. +1 to @vic and @sdg. To understand if an architecture follows a certain style, you have to understand both that style and the architecture. Sorry, this requires real work on your part.

Comment: Ok. I had the confusion so I have asked. I had the confusion about the Client side interface of REST.

Answer (score 0):

Given an URL, you are following the REST architectural style if

a) you have no knowledge of what media type is going to be returned from that URL, instead you as a client indicate what media-types you support using the accept header and you react based on what media type is returned and

b) the only actions you take are based on information embedded in the returned response.  i.e.  You only follow links that are in the returned response.

Comment: But it is no different than any HTML page link. There also I send accept headers. and there also I can take based on the information returned!

Comment: @Satya  Exactly.  HTML and web browsers are one of the most common examples of REST in action.